# how to implement an "If error wait for 15min then continue"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, twitter, twitterapi-python

I am trying to scrape data(liking user of tweets) from twitter and save to a sqlite3 database. The twitter API allows us to do 75 requests at once then raises a "too many requests" error. I want to implement a mechanism to: if there is an error we will wait for 15min then continue. The program should not start over but continue to send the requests where the error was raised and 15min of sleep time.
Any ideas please!!
for the getClient() one should have his own credintials
my code is:

```py
import pandas as pd
import json

def getClient():
    client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=BEARER_TOKEN,
                           consumer_key=API_KEY,
                           consumer_secret=API_KEY_SECRET,
                           access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN,
                           access_token_secret=ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
    return client
def intersection(lst1, lst2):
    lst3 = [value for value in lst1 if value not in lst2]
    return lst3

def addLikers(client):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("data.db")
    ids = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT tweetId FROM searchTweets", conn)['tweetId'].tolist()
    likes = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT tweetId FROM LikingUsers", conn)['tweetId'].tolist()
    communVals = intersection(ids, likes)
    c = conn.cursor()
    for communVal in communVals:
# the function should be here
        likingUsers = client.get_liking_users(communVal)
        row = [(communVal), (json.dumps(likingUsers.data))]
        c.executemany("INSERT INTO searchFollowers VALUES (?,?)", (row,))
        conn.commit()

addLikers(client)
```

For now I am just committing the results until i get the error. To create the table in sqlite3:

```py
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("data.db")

c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE LikingUsers (
        tweetId integer,
        reply text
        )""")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `signal`:

```
    def signal_handler(signum, frame):
        raise Exception("Timed out!")

  # limit the time before specific function
            signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, signal_handler)
            signal.alarm(60 * 15)  # 15 minuets
```